# Trying to traverse the DOM, but getting Uncaught TypeError parentNode is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, dom, runtime-error

I'm trying to move away from jQuery into plain javascript, but am having difficulty traversing the DOM as I did with jQuery. I'm getting an **"Uncaught TypeError: html.parentNode is undefined"** error, after writing to the DOM, when trying to move back up the DOM structure. Here's the code:

Javascript

```
let html = 'change to this';

let eA = document.querySelector('.startA');

eA.parentNode
    .querySelector('.target1A .target2A')
    .innerHTML = html
    .parentNode
    .querySelector('.target1A')
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');
```

HTML

```
<div id="top">
    <div class="startA">
        <div class="target1A hidden">
            <div class="target2A">target 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. I think I'm not completely understanding how to move through the DOM yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator has low precedence. Your code is equivalent to:

```
const result = html
    .parentNode
    .querySelector('.target1A')
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');

eA.parentNode
    .querySelector('.target1A .target2A')
    .innerHTML = result;
```

Which doesn't work - you can't chain the assignment operator like you're trying to do. Select the element after inserting the HTML, as a separate statement.

You also don't need to select `target1A`, since it's already the parent of the `target2A`.

```
const target = eA.parentNode.querySelector('.target1A .target2A');
target.innerHTML = html;
target.parentNode
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');
```

```js
const eA = document.querySelector('.startA');
const target = eA.parentNode.querySelector('.target1A .target2A');
target.innerHTML = 'foobar';
target.parentNode
    .classList
    .remove('hidden');
```

```html
<div id="top">
    <div class="startA">
        <div class="target1A hidden">
            <div class="target2A">target 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you wanted to do this in a chainable fashion, and since your question is tagged with jQuery, you can use that:

```
$('.startA')
  .find('.target1A .target2A')
  .html(html)
  .parent()
  .removeClass('hidden');
```

```js
$('.startA')
  .find('.target1A .target2A')
  .html('foobar')
  .parent()
  .removeClass('hidden');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
    <div class="startA">
        <div class="target1A hidden">
            <div class="target2A">target 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Got it. I see how this works now. Thanks for the example and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let html = 'change to this';
    let eA = document.querySelector('.startA');
    eA.parentNode
        .querySelector('.target1A .target2A')
        .innerHTML = html;
    eA.parentNode
        .parentNode
        .querySelector('.target1A')
        .classList
        .remove('hidden');
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I think you've got an extra 'parentNode' in there.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice the parent node. Anyways, you're welcome